# Returning oneliner from SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this code to return many rows as one row in SQL Server 2008. It works nicely and returns numbers that are divided with `;`. But it's also true when there's only one row to return and then I don't really need `;` to be shown at all. Same applies to having `;` for last value. What's the best way to fix it without impacting performance of this query?

```
SELECT (        
    SELECT [KontaktyWartosc] + '; '  FROM [PodmiotyKontakty]
    INNER JOIN [Klienci]
    ON [PodmiotyKontakty].[PodmiotID] = [Klienci].[PodmiotID] 
    WHERE [KlienciID] = @idKlienta AND
    FOR XML PATH('')) AS CONTENT
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse the order of the concatenation and use `SUBSTRING`. 
8000 avoids an extra `LEN` and you can use 2000000000 for `(max)` types too

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING (
        (        
            SELECT '; ' + [KontaktyWartosc]   FROM [PodmiotyKontakty]
            INNER JOIN [Klienci]
            ON [PodmiotyKontakty].[PodmiotID] = [Klienci].[PodmiotID] 
            WHERE [KlienciID] = @idKlienta AND
            FOR XML PATH('')) AS CONTENT
        ), 3, 8000)
```